# Add Actionbarsherlock in Idea Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

Tell please me as add Actionbarsherlock in the Idea Intellij. I tried different ways, not fails. I have added from is File -> Import Module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this [guide](http://android-wtf.com/2012/09/how-to-configure-actionbarsherlock-with-intellij-idea/), it should help you.

Comment: I try this guide. My test example fail when compiling. Probable i wrong add components or wrong create test application.

Comment: This guide was written for Idea Intellij 11.  It no longer appears relevant to version 13.